# Identifying frauds while salting passwords

Tags: security, passwords, salt

Im in the works of updating the login process of a site.

Currently, passwords are stored as md5(password), and i'd like to add a salt,
but the unsalted password is being used to identify possible frauds since they
usually uses the same password for new accounts.

20% of the traffic is from mobile devices, which don't necessarily have the same ip.

Any idea how to identify these possible frauds?

Comment: How will you differentiate frauds from all the people who put "password" as their password?

Comment: If a user has been banned for fraud, and creates a new account, the new accounts password will be compared to other users, and if it matches any suspicious accounts, will be investigated further.

Comment: So these frauds aren't very smart, are they?

Comment: Don't store unsalted passwords. By doing so under *ANY PREMISE WHATSOEVER* you are reducing the security and potentially the privacy of all of your users if the database gets compromised. Using the same password is not a good detection for "fraud" users anyway, so you have no good reason to store unsalted passwords in your database at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can still add a salt, but you have to do the comparison to the existing passwords while you still have the plaintext password, i.e. you'll have to loop through the passwords table looking for duplicates (by hashing the other account's salt with the new password) at the time the account is created rather than afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I would say salting passwords is definitely a major benefit over keeping them unsalted for fraud prevention purposes. However, please use [a cryptographically secure slow hashing algorithm, such as bcrypt, scrypt or pbkdf2](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/31846/8340) - not salted MD5.

But you could have your cake and eat it, why not have another table that contains previous passwords that have been used in fraud attempts? These would be hashed, but not salted and would not have any account association stored.

If a user that uses one of these passwords turns out to be non-fraudulent, you could give them a notification to change their password to something else after you have investigated.

Here's how I imagine it would work for adding new passwords to the fraudulent password list after an account is determined to be used for fraud.

1. Account is marked as fraudulent.
2. When this user next attempts to log in, and their hashed, salted password matches the hashed, salted value stored in their account record, the unsalted hashed password taken from their user input is stored in the fraudulent password list.

As the fraudulent password list *could* reduce the security of the accounts of upstanding users because they are stored in here unsalted, you should make "good" users change their passwords upon login if it matches any in the fraudulent password list.

Comment: If the database was exposed, wouldn't this just be providing a full list of used passwords, ruining the purpose of salting the user table?

Comment: You'd only be storing the passwords of accounts that were previously used in fraud, which presumably you would have been deactivated anyway? If a non-fraudulent user used one of these passwords, you could give them a notification to change their password to something else after you have investigated.

Comment: If there is an account with a salted password that you decide to ban, how are you going to obtain an unsalted password to put in your list of unsalted "fraud" passwords without storing the original password (which would be bad)?

Comment: Here's how I imagine it would work: 1) Account is marked as fraudulent. 2) When this user next attempts to log in, and their hashed, salted password matches the hashed, salted value stored in their account record, at this point store the unsalted hashed password in the fraud password list.